# Drop columns in multiple tables at once using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used Microsoft SQL Server to create a database with hundreds of tables. I would like to delete four columns in some of the tables, which the four columns were exact same in these tables.

I just know the simplest ways to do it, which is typing the alter statement out one by one. However, this is obviously too time consuming that's why I'm trying to look for some more efficient way.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLEA DROP COLUMN1
ALTER TABLE TABLEA DROP COLUMN2
ALTER TABLE TABLEA DROP COLUMN3
ALTER TABLE TABLEB DROP COLUMN1
ALTER TABLE TABLEB DROP COLUMN2
ALTER TABLE TABLEB DROP COLUMN3
...
```

Comment: `select 'alter table ' + quotename(so.name) + ' drop column ' + quotename(sc.name) from sys.tables so inner join sys.columns sc on sc.object_id = so.object_id where sc.name IN ('column1', 'column2', 'column3')`

Comment: Could there be any tables where you *want* these columns to remain? Are these columns part of any `CONSTRAINT`s or `INDEX`es?

Comment: You can only alter one table at a time. You can drop multiple columns on the same table, ie `ALTER TABLE TABLEA DROP COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3`.

Answer (score -1):

You can only alter one table at a time. You can drop multiple columns on the same table, ie `ALTER TABLE TABLEA DROP COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3`.

To apply the same `ALTER TABLE` on multiple tables you can use the undocumented but frequently used [sp_MSforeachtable](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-introduction-to-sp_msforeachtable-run-commands-iteratively-through-all-tables-in-a-database/) stored procedure :

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? DROP COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3'
```

Normally, the stored procedure is applied to all tables. You can use the `@whereand` parameter to restrict it to specific tables.

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 
    @command1='ALTER TABLE ? DROP COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3',
    @whereand='AND object_name(o.id) IN(''Table1'', ''Table2'')'
```

As the linked article shows, `sp_MSforeachtable` uses the `dbo.sysobjects` table to find all matching tables. The `OBJECT_NAME` is used to retrieve the name of a table from its ID.

The linked article shows how you can filter by schema as well, using the `schema_id` field of `sysobjects`.

```
@whereand='AND schema_name(schema_id) = ''HumanResources'''
```

Answer (score -2):

To drop the same columns from multiple tables in a SQL Server, you can use a dynamic SQL script. in this way creates and runs the necessary ALTER TABLE statements for each table:

1. Find the Tables: First, find that which tables have the columns you want to remove. You can get these information from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table.
2. For each table you identified, put together the ALTER TABLE commands needed to drop the columns.

Run this command:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @sql += 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) 
               + ' DROP COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + '; '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3')
AND TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE ...);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Replace your criteria with ... , and finally execute the dynamic query with sp_executesql.

Comment: This perhaps with some help from chatgpt

Comment: Using the syntax `SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your data in a row by row order, which there is *no* guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using `STRING_AGG`, however, in older versions you'll need to use `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) to achieve the same results.

Comment: Also `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is for compatibility only, use `sys.columns` instead.